# unexpected VARSYM in zimpl

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, scip

I am getting an unexpected VARSYM in my Zimpl code. Here is a portion of my code:

```
param T := 0.8;
var S[Sensors] binary;

minimize nb_sensors : sum < i > in Sensors : S[ i ];

subto fd:

     1- prod <k,l>  in Sensors*Pipe : (1-ord(Proba[k,l],1,1) * S[k])  >= T;
```

It seems that the error is because I have a variable (`S[]`) which is inside the function (`prod`), do you have any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

What is T, a variable or a constant? Have you tried to write the product in brackets:

```
1- (prod <k,l>  in Sensors*Pipe : (1-ord(Proba[k,l],1,1) * S[k]))  >= T;
```

or to rewrite is as:

```
prod <k,l>  in Sensors*Pipe : (1-ord(Proba[k,l],1,1) * S[k]) + T <= 1;
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried both of them, but the same error occur. However, when I tried to replace `prod` with `sum`, no error has occurred!! What do you think? may be it is a bug in `prod` function?

Comment: Ok. I think the problem is that zimpl cannot handle term with variable products of size greater than 2, ie, bilinear term are fine. Each constraint of your type fd looks like: ((1-a)*S[1])*((1-b)*S[2])*...*((1-k)*S[k])

Comment: Each constraint look like: `(1-(a*S[1]) )  * (1-(b*S[2]) ) *(1-(c*S[3]) ) ....` what is the solution for this case in your opinion ?

Comment: Are you aware about any other language that can handle such product?? Thanks for all your comments.

Comment: There are commercial languages, eg, mosel (xpress) and gams, that maybe handle those constraints. I think in you case it would be the easiest way to implement your problem directly within a solver, eg, scip.